# check if exe is in the desktop c#

Tags: c#, directory

How can I check if my WinForm application is being executed from the desktop or any sub-directory of the desktop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
```

This will give path to desktop.And you can compare it to your exe file path

```
  String exePath = Application.StartupPath;

  public Boolean IsRunningFromDesktop(String exePath){
       String desktopPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);    
       return (exePath.Contains(desktopPath);
    }
```